# Redefinition of main

Tags: c, program-entry-point

I started writing code in C, and I needed the `toupper` function in my code, so I added to `ctype.h` header file to include it.

All of a sudden I can't run my program because I keep getting a `redefinition of main` error from my compiler.

Before I added the header `ctype.h`, and even if I get rid of the header file `ctype.h`, the program runs. What do I do to fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define NAMESPACE 20

int main (void)
{  

    char first_name[NAMESPACE], middle_name[NAMESPACE], last_name[NAMESPACE];
    printf ("Please enter your first, middle and last name.\n");
    scanf ("%s", first_name);
    scanf("%s", middle_name);
    scanf ("%s", last_name);
    printf ("%s %0.1s %s", first_name, middle_name, last_name);
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
[error] redefinition of "int main()":
```

Here is the code saved as a header file called ctype.h in my DEV c++ ,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main (void)
{
char ch[]="I AM AN IDIOT.";
char c='A';
int i=0;
while(c)
{
c=getch();
printf("%c\a",ch[i]);
i++;
if(i==14)
{
printf(" "); i=0;
}
}
}
```

Comment: The code looks OK to me. What's your platform?

Comment: I'm a beginner at this I Don't know. I'm using DEV c++.

Comment: I have no idea how to help you further. I am able to create a program from your posted code with gcc and it runs. The format `%0.1s` produces a warning but the program runs.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your project in dev+c++?

Comment: Is that the entire error message? Does it refer to a line number? To a file?

Comment: Any chance you are accidently linkin in 2 different projects that you created?

Comment: `NAMESPACE` as a constant also scares me, though it should be fine.

Comment: John bollinger was right with his second guess. The ctype.h header file was modified to be an odd c program. Now i need to figure out how change it back to normal.

Comment: The '%0.1s' format specifier is incorrect.  it should be (either) '%1s' or '%.1s' with the first printing 1 char and the second printing 'at least' one char (this will be clearer when using larger values and a short string)

Answer (score 7):

The code you posted does not explain the error message you presented.  It has some issues, but none that should elicit any error.  There are several possible reasons for the error, among them:

1. My best guess would be that you have another source file in the project that has its own `main()` function, and the IDE is configured to include both in the same target program.  That might result simply by virtue of them being collocated in the same directory.  That other source file might even be something dumb, such as a backup copy of the file you presented.
2. Alternatively, it may be that you have a project-local header named `ctype.h`, which defines a `main()` function, and Dev C++ is choosing that one instead of the standard library's header.  (Yes, this is really just a variant on (1); there's not much leeway in "redefinition of 'int main()'".)
3. Or perhaps Dev C++ misspoke, and it's complaining about a re*declaration* of `main()` rather than a re*definition*.  If its `ctype.h` header contained a conflicting declaration, such as `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, then it might issue a complaint.  In that unlikely case, you might be able to resolve the error by changing the declaration of your `main()` to the two-argument form.

Comment: Yes you were right on number 2. When i clicked the error message, a program that i've never seen before came up, and it was named ctype.h, and saved as a header file. It had a main function in it as well. How do I get the standard ctype.h file header back?

Comment: If you are sure that the `ctype.h` you found *isn't* Dev C++'s version of the standard library header, and especially if it's in one of your project directories rather than somewhere in one of Dev C++'s system directories, then you can probably just delete it.  If a rogue file has actually replaced one of Dev C++'s standard headers, then I would completely wipe Dev C++ from the system, and install a fresh copy from a trusted source.

Comment: suggestion '3' will raise two warnings about unused parameters, unless the code is drastically changed to use those two parameters.

Comment: @user3629249, indeed, yes, adding the `argc` and `argv` parameters would likely cause the compiler to raise warnings.  So?  If the problem had been that there was a conflicting declaration of `main()` in one of the standard headers, then there would not have been a good alternative.  It's important to understand what a warning is telling you, but certain warnings simply need to be ignored or suppressed.